# When i hover over the help icon the tool tip hides behind the header tab

Tags: html, tooltip

When i hover over the question mark icon, the tool tip gets hide behind the header tab.

Look the attached image!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUouZ.png)

i need the tool tip to come above the header tab without getting hide.

This is my CSS [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evF3U.jpg)

```
.showmeonhover { display: none; }
        .label-input100:hover .showmeonhover {
              display: inline;
              width: auto;
              background-color: white;
              color: #fff;
              text-align: left;
              border-radius: 6px;
              padding: 5px 0;
              border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
              bottom: 125%;
              background-color: #555;
              /* Position the tooltip */
              position: absolute;
              margin-left: -100px;
              margin-bottom: -18px;
              padding-left: 6px;
              padding-right: 5px;
              z-index: 200; 
              font-size: 8px !important;
              text-transform:capitalize !important;
          }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: you should show your code.

Comment: @lilfancy he have attached HTML/CSS code in question

Comment: i don't see any code attached to the question @Logeshwaran

Comment: @lilfancy can u please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the z-index in your css-class.

like:

```
.headerTab{
    z-index: 0;
}

.showmeonhover{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @AMIIDIOT Did you specify a position? (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: i have used "position:relative" for header. And position absolute for tooltip class. if i remove position for headertab nothing changes. But if i remove position for tooltip it gets crash like layout issue. @bursac

Comment: @AMIIDIOT Define the position for both (headertab and showmeonhover)

Comment: i have defined position for both (headertab and showmeonhover) please check the updated question for my code. but not working @bursac

Comment: @AMIIDIOT Can you specify z-index for .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header (lower than the z-index from .showmeonhover )

Comment: i gave "z-index: 9999;" for ".showmeonhover" and "z-index: 3;" for ".ui-accordian-content" and "z-index: 0;" for ".ui-accordian-header" . Still not working bro :(